# Is there something like news feed and rss for different tags?

Tags: feature-request

Is there any way to have last questions [that I haven't seen yet] of some tags in a single page with notification?

i.e. I want to have for example `n` notifications in top bar for `n` new questions of `m` tags that have been asked in SO from my previous sign in.

I know that this is not useful for famous tags (because we have a lot of questions in a short time), but for some tags that we have about 1 question per 2 day, it seems useful to aggregate them in a single proprietary tag! for example I want to have `EMV`, `SmartCard`, `JavaCard`, ... in a single tag named `MyFavoriteQuestions`.

Is there any way?

Comment: You can get an RSS feed for any combination of tags. Either use the url `https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=tag1+tag2+...+tagN&sort=newest`, or search for the Tags and scroll to the bottom of the result page, where you will find a link to the RSS feed.

Comment: As far as I know, In the `newest` tab I see all the questions sorted by the time that those asked. not those one that added from the previous login. right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is RSS feed for tags, not news feed.

You can see the tag feed by **mouseover** on that tag and then click on **rss**, which you can find in the *right top corner* of popup after mouseover.

Here is the **RSS feed** of [support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/support).

[Check this link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/support).

Comment: May you please suggest an alternative for the Google Reader also? (An online tool)

Comment: @Abraham check this: http://gizmodo.com/10-google-reader-alternatives-that-will-ease-your-rss-p-5990540